# How to parse string without any surround with pegjs?

Tags: pegjs

There is a text:

```
this is title. {this is id} [this is type] (this is description)
```

I want to get the follow object

```
{
    id: 'this is id',
    title: 'this is title',
    type: 'this is type',
    description: 'this is description',
}
```

this is my pegjs rules:

```
start = Text

_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t\n\r]*

Text
    = _ body:Element? _ {
        return {
            type: "Text",
            body: body || [],
        }
    }

Element
    = _ title:Title _ id:Id _ type:Type _ description:Description _ {
        return {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            type: type,
            description: description,
        }
    }

Type
    = "[" type: Literal "]" {
        return type;
    }

Id
    = '{' id: Literal '}' {
        return id;
    }

Title
    = Literal

Description
    = "(" description: Literal ")" {
        return description;
    }

Literal "Literal"
    = '"' char:DoubleStringCharacter* '"' {
        return char.join("");
    }

DoubleStringCharacter
    = !'"' . {
        return text();
    }
```

There is the question, I don't know how to match the string without any surround syntax?

I only know the Literal grammar is wrong, but I don't know how to improve it, can anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Literal` rule accepts quoted strings, what you can do is when you are parsing id, you match everything until you find a `}`, when you parse type you match everything until you see a `]`, when you parse description you match everything until you see `)`, and when parsing the title you match everything until you see a `.` then your rule `Element` will produce the result you want.

```js
start = Text

_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t\n\r]*

Text
    = _ body:Element? _ {
        return {
            type: "Text",
            body: body || [],
        }
    }

Element
    = _ title:Title _ id:Id _ type:Type _ description:Description _ {
        return {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            type: type,
            description: description,
        }
    }

Type
    = "[" type: $[^\]]* "]" {
        return type;
    }

Id
    = '{' id: $[^}]* '}' {
        return id;
    }

Title
    = s:$[^.]* '.' _ {return s}

Description
    = "(" description: $[^)]* ")" {
        return description;
    }
```

Comment: Oh it is work! but title rules should be:
```
Title
    = s:$[^{]*  _ {return s}
```
I do not realize i can use [^] to match the string. Thank you very muck!

Comment: Thank you for the return, my choice of the Title rule was based purely on your example, of course you can extend this in many directions :)